# Select2 Programmatic Access

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using jQuery [Select2](http://select2.github.io/select2/) and I am running into an issue setting a value and triggering an event.

I have a simple select2 dropdown hooked up to an Ajax source. This works perfectly fine.

I also have an event waiting for a select2 option to be chosen:

```
 // On project select, we add the projects to the list along with the parties
$('.projSearch').on("select2-selecting", function(e) {

    // Set the value of the project
    var projectID = e.val,
        table = '';

        alert(projectID);
        console.log(e);

      ...
```

When using the select2 dropdown like normal, this event works fine. It detects the data of the option you select.

However, I am also including a button on the page that allows a user to set the data of the field. It sets the data just fine, however it never triggers the event `select2-selecting`.

I tried passing the data along with the event but not matter what when the `select2-selecting` event is fired, it returns `undefined`.

```
$(document).on("click", "[name=addProject]", function() {

    // Set the vars
    var projectName = $(this).attr('projectname'),
        projectID = $(this).attr('projectid'),
        projectNameLong = projectName + ' ('+projectID+')';

    // Add the project to the list  
    $("[name=projects]").select2("data", [{id: projectID, text: projectNameLong}]).trigger("select2-selecting", {val: projectID, data: {id: projectID, text: projectNameLong}});

});
```

How can I pass data along with the trigger to I can access it within the event?

Thanks for any info!

Comment: does the event actually fire, when you do it like in the second snippet?

Comment: It adds it to the select field and it shows up just fine. However, there is no data passed along with it so the alert / console for `e` is always undefined

Comment: as far as I remember your data is accessible not directly on the event object, but in the e.data property

Comment: Strange, when I do `console.log(e)` the data attribute says undefined.

Comment: but event should not be undefined anyway

Comment: try `.trigger(jQuery.Event( "select2-selecting" ) ....` instead of simply passing the string `select2-selecting`

Comment: That did not work unfortunately

Comment: try to put `debugger` right before the `console.log` call to see what is in your `e` variable at exact the same moment. I suppose console might show a reference to an object which holds undefined after the handler finishes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select2 [normally triggers the `select2-selecting` event](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/03c44997527eabf4656a44c0ac0a1a259b36730a/select2.js#L1157-L1158) by [creating a `$.Event` object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) with the custom data containing the `val` and `data` attributes that you are looking for. [The second parameter of `.trigger`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/#trigger-event-extraParameters) will allow you to get extra data directly from within the event handler, but it doesn't attach it to the event object.

```
$(document).on("click", "[name=addProject]", function() {
    // Set the vars
    var projectName = $(this).attr('projectname'),
        projectID = $(this).attr('projectid'),
        projectNameLong = projectName + ' ('+projectID+')';

    // Create the data object
    var data = {
        id: projectID,
        text: projectNameLong
    };

    // Create the custom event object
    var evt = $.Event("select2-selecting", {
        val: data.id,
        data: data
    });

    // Add the project to the list  
    $("[name=projects]")
        .select2("data", [data])
        .trigger(evt);
});
```

This should replicate the original `select2-selecting` event for you and allow you to reuse your event handler.